# Remove multiple new lines to 1 new line from a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

2 parameters `file_in` and `file_out` and I need to convert (`'a\n\n\n\na'`) to (`'a\n\na'`) multiple times. I tried with `re.sub(r'[\r\n][\r\n]{2,}', '\n\n', file_out)` but nothing works Anyone have an idea?

```
         --------------------
          aaa


          bbb




          ccc
          --------------------

    needed to be converted to

          --------------------
          aaa

          bbb

          ccc
          --------------------
```

Comment: Is the line ending CRLF or LF? Try `re.sub(r'\r\n(?:\r\n){2,}', '\r\n\r\n', file_out)`

Comment: or `"\n\n".join([x for x in s.splitlines() if x])`